# Posterior Probabilities in terms log odds ratio

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, naive-bayes

From the book Bayesian Decision Analysis Principles and Practice, I am trying to prove

$$\begin{aligned} \mathbb{P}(I=i\mid X=x)=\frac{\exp(O(i,1\mid x))}{1+\sum_{k=2}^n \exp(O(k,1\mid x))} \end{aligned}$$

Where $O(i,k\mid x)=log\left( \frac{\mathbb{P}(I=i\mid X=x)}{\mathbb{P}(I=k\mid X=x)}\right) $

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$O(i,k\mid x)=log\left( \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=x\mid I=i)}{\mathbb{P}(X=x\mid I=k)}\right)$$ instead?

Comment: No as it is the posterior log odds of I @mhdadk

Answer (score 0):

Just to save on notation, let $P_i = P(I=i|X=x)$

$$P_i=\frac{\exp(log(\frac{P_i}{P_1}))}{1+\sum_{k=2}^n \exp(log(\frac{P_k}{P_1}))}$$

$$ = \frac{\frac{P_i}{P_1}}{1+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{P_k}{P_1}}$$

$$ = \frac{\frac{P_i}{P_1}}{1+\frac{1}{P_1}\sum_{k=2}^n P_k}$$

Assuming that $\sum_{k=1}^n P_k = 1$, then $\sum_{k=2}^n P_k = 1 - P_1$

$$ = \frac{\frac{P_i}{P_1}}{1+\frac{1}{P_1}(1-P_1)} = P_i$$